# PHP passing a variable with header redirect

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a variable within a header link. I have tried below code

```
$name = "mike";

if($name != "lopan"){
        header("Location:error-page.php?$errorMssg=Please enter information?");
}
```

This page redirect to location  but doesn't pass the variable that contains the message. But when i create a simple link with values like this:

```
<a href="error-page.php?$errorMssg=so what happened there buddy?">link</a>
```

it passes it just fine.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong? or  i can  not pass information with headers?

Comment: You don't need the $ character in the URL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) like this:

```
if($name != "lopan"){
        header("Location:error-page.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Waoo so your not EVEN going to try to enter information huh?"));
}
```

And in error-page.php, you should get it (no need to urldecode):

```
<?php
$errorMssg = $_GET['errorMssg'];
```

Comment: Lols, is this a header thing as far as not adding the "$" in the link or??? because when i did a regular link with it, it passed just fine.

Comment: You don't need any `$`'s when passing arguments in urls. You need a `?` to indicate the beginning of the parameters, and a `&` between each, like this: `http://example.com?foo=bar&baz=baz`. Don't confuse this with the PHP variables that start with a `$`.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `$` before `errorMssg` and `urlencode` the message.

Answer (score 1):

could it be because you have `$errorMssg` instead of `$errorMsg` ? also try to make a valid url, for example replace " " with %20 etc, function `urlencode()` could help you with this.